# Pandas pivot table to replace multiple hit by a string

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I used pandas `melt` function to make a table which looks almost like,

```
ref   Class   Sam
A      v1      1
A      v2      1
A      v2      1
B      v1      1
C      v2      1
A      v1      2
B      v2      2
B      v3      2
C      v1      2
```

And I was trying to create a matrix using `pivot_table` function

```
melt.pivot_table(index='ref', columns='Sam', values='Class', aggfunc=lambda x: ';'.join(x.unique())).fillna('')
```

Which gives me something like this

```
      1        2
A   v1;v2     v1
B     v1     v2;v3
C     v2      v1
```

Instead, I want to edit this code in such a way it replaces the multiple occurrences to a string while keeping the single occurrences as such.

For example;

```
      1        2
A  MultiHit   v1
B     v1    MultiHit
C     v2      v1
```

Any suggestions?

Please let me know if my question wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

use `replace` with `regex=True`

```
df.pivot_table(index='ref', columns='Sam', values='Class', aggfunc=lambda x: ';'.join(x.unique())).fillna('').replace('(\w+;\w+|;\w+)+','MultiHit',regex=True)
```

---

```
Sam         1         2
ref                    
A    MultiHit        v1
B          v1  MultiHit
C          v2        v1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `groupby` and update where needed, then unstack:

```
# replace count with nunique if necessary
new_df = df.groupby(['ref','Sam'])['Class'].agg({'count','first'})
new_df.loc[new_df['count'].gt(1), 'first'] = 'MultiHit'

new_df['first'].unstack('Sam')
```

Output:

```
Sam         1         2
ref                    
A    MultiHit        v1
B          v1  MultiHit
C          v2        v1
```

---

Pivot can be used also without later unstack:

```
new_df = df.pivot_table(index='ref', 
                        columns='Sam',
                        values='Class', 
                        aggfunc=['count', 'first'])

new_df.loc[:,'first'] = np.where(new_df.loc[:,'count'].gt(1), 
                                 'MultiHist', 
                                 new_df.loc[:,'first'])

new_df.loc[:,'first']
```

also gives the same output.